# Have all "ipad mini 2"s a retina display?

Tags: ipad, display

I want to buy a *iPad mini 2* and I'm searching about it. Actually I'm confused. Somewhere people call it just "iPad mini 2" and somewhere else "iPad mini 2 with retina display" ..!

Ok, all of them have retina display? Or there is some iPad mini 2 which don't have a retina display?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, every model of the iPad mini 2 has a retina display. Those who call it the "iPad mini 2" are likely just using a shortened form of the name for convenience.

Source: [apple.com](http://www.apple.com/shop/buy-ipad/ipad-mini-2)

Comment: So there isn't any ipad mini 2 *without** retina display. right?

Comment: I can't find one at apple.com. I've never seen one.